# "Tu ne devrais pas fumer" contre "Tu devrais ne pas fumer"

Tags: négation, infinitif, verbes-modaux

Quelle est la différence entre les deux phrases ci-dessous ?

> "Tu ne devrais pas fumer"
>
> "Tu devrais ne pas fumer"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

La première est idiomatique. On y **déconseille** de fumer :

> Tu **ne** devrais **pas** fumer.

Dans la deuxième phrase on **recommande** de ne pas fumer.

> (?) Tu devrais **ne pas** fumer.

C'est compréhensible et ne choque pas outre-mesure l'oreille car *ne pas fumer* est une construction courante, mais cette tournure est très peu employée car elle ne respecte pas la position de la négation *ne pas*  qui, dans les temps composés, doit entourer l’auxiliaire. ex:

> J'ai fumé.
>
> Je **n**'ai **pas** fumé.
>
> <s>J'ai **ne pas** fumé.</s>

Devoir est ici un verbe modal (semi-auxiliaire). Il précède l'infinitif et suit les usages des auxiliaires.

Avec un verbe non modal, la deuxième forme est préférée :

> (?) Je **ne** préfère **pas** fumer.
>
> Je préfère **ne pas fumer**.

Quand *devoir* n'est pas modal, la position de la négation *ne pas* est imposée :

> Je dois dix euros à mon frère.
>
> Je **ne** dois **pas** dix euros à mon frère.
>
> <s>Je dois ne pas dix euros à mon frère.</s>

Le *ne* tendant à disparaître dans la langue parlée, le problème ne se pose plus :

> Tu devrais pas fumer.
>
> J'ai pas fumé.
>
> Je préfère pas fumer.

Answer (score 2):

La formulation **tu ne devrais pas** est beaucoup plus idiomatique, mais en terme de signification, ces expressions sont équivalentes.